# How to find correct python interpreter from PYCHARM and use that same one in cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm

I have code that works great in PyCharm and i have the python interpreter set as 'Python 3.7/usr/local/python3.7'.

The problem is that when i go to CMD and type 'python --version' it says 'Python 2.7.10'

I have multiple envs on my system and i want to run a .py file from CMD with the same python interpreter as in Pycharm but i just cant figure out how to use the same settings in CMD as in Pycharm.

Is there anyway of me using 'Python 3.7/usr/local/python3.7' in the CMD? How would I find it?

I have python 3.7, i want to use it in CMD.

Comment: why do You have the 2.7 version still? is it necessary? because otherwise it is deprecated and You can just delete it, can't You?

Comment: I guess you need to upgrade your python in your computer. You can look at here: https://dev.to/serhatteker/how-to-upgrade-to-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04-18-10-5hab

Comment: oh no i have python 3.7 but what i mean is how do i get to that environment that has 3.7? because when i just use command it says 2.7 but in pycharm i am using 3.7 so how can i get and use that env in the CMD?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `Python 3.7/usr/local/python3.7` is a folder on your computer. Walk us through the exact steps of how you installed Python, how any existing Python installations happened to be on your computer already, and also explain what operating system you are using.

Comment: I'm on MacOS using PyCharm and on PyCharm it says: Python interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.7   Now when i type python --version into terminal it says : Python 2.7.10

Comment: So when on cmd, prefix the full path to your desired python, that is  /usr/local/bin/python3.7/bin/python.